# ¿Cómo crear dos bordes que separe el texto principal?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Estoy tratando de crear dos bordes una a la izquierda y otra a la derecha y el texto principal quede en el medio de los dos bordes.

Un ejemplo a la idea a lo que estoy tratando de lograr he subido dos imágenes de muestra.

Traté realizando de esta manera pero las dos lineas se juntan.

```
    <div class="www">

      <h4><span class="lineseparator"></span>
        TITLE NOT TITLE
        <span class="lineseparator"></span>
      </h4>

      <p>Content and content and contecnt</p>
    </div>
```

Intenté de esta otra forma pero el mismo problema.

```
    <div class="www">
      <span class="lineseparator"></span>
      <h4>TITLE NOT TITLE</h4>
      <span class="lineseparator"></span>
      <p>Content and content and contecnt</p>
    </div>
```

**Ejecución:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'OpenSans', 'cursive', 'Releway', Roboto, Lato, Utsaah;
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
}
.www {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
.lineseparator {
height: 1px;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 12px;
width: 20%;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
    <div class="www">
      <span class="lineseparator"></span>
      <h4>TITLE NOT TITLE</h4>
      <span class="lineseparator"></span>
      <p>Content and content and contecnt</p>
    </div>

<br><br><br>
    <div class="www">
      
      <h4><span class="lineseparator"></span>
        TITLE NOT TITLE
        <span class="lineseparator"></span>
      </h4>
      
      <p>Content and content and contecnt</p>
    </div>
```

Lo que deseo lograr es lo siguiente el ejemplo lo tome de un sitio web.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y que al hacer responsive se adapte de la siguiente manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otro modo de hacerlo sería usando los pseudo-elementos `::before` y `::after` junto con Flexbox. Este método es (o al menos me parece) bastante interesante porque no hacen falta etiquetas adicionales, sólo con el `h4` ya funcionará.

La idea es:

- Añade `display:flex` al encabezado.
- Añade los dos pseudo-elementos `::before` y `::after` vacíos con un borde superior.
- Ponle `flex:1` a los pseudo-elementos para que ocupen todo el espacio disponible.
- Usa transformaciones para desplazar los pseudo-elementos un 50% del alto.

Y aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```css
h4 {
  display:flex;
}

h4::before, h4::after {
  content:"";
  flex:1;
  border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
  margin:0px 10px;
  transform:translateY(50%)
}
```

```html
<h4>TÍTULO CON BORDES LATERALES</h4>
```

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro es perfecto todos los ejemplos que me has indicado funciona perfectamente sin problemas al igual que a ti a mi también me parece muy interesante esta forma más que todo por las pocas líneas de código y más aún porque en el código fuente de la imagen también utilizaba ´flex´ pero creo que no lo copie bien o no lo supe imitar a pesar de observar el código pero fantástico el ejemplo gracias :)

Answer (score 3):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```css
.in-middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.tittle-pad-size {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="in-middle">
  <span class="tittle-pad-size">What you get?</span>
</div>

<div class="www">
  <p>Course for all!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer de diferentes maneras. Un modo sencillo sería por ejemplo usando un pseudo-elemento `::after` para hacer la línea horizontal, y luego superponer el texto con un `span` que tenga el mismo fondo que el de la página.

Algo como esto:

```css
h4 {
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}

h4 span {
   background: white;
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
   padding:0px 10px;
}

h4::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<h4>
  <span>TÍTULO DE SECCIÓN</span>
</h4>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    /*
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'OpenSans', 'cursive', 'Releway', Roboto, Lato, Utsaah;
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
}/*
.www {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
.lineseparator {
height: 1px;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 12px;
width: 20%;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
}*/


.primero{
  border-left:4px red solid;
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<!--
 <div class="www">
      <span class="lineseparator"></span>
      <h4>TITLE NOT TITLE</h4>
      <span class="lineseparator"></span>
      <p>Content and content and contecnt</p>
    </div>

<br><br><br>
    <div class="www">
      
      <h4><span class="lineseparator"></span>
        TITLE NOT TITLE
        <span class="lineseparator"></span>
      </h4>
      
      <p>Content and content and contecnt</p>
    </div>-->


<CENTER>
    <div class="primero">
    <h3>TITULO</h3>
    <P>INFORMACION BLABLABLA</P>

      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Algo asi pero curviada?

Comment: Esta respuesta puede ser correcta, pero sin ningún tipo de explicación no creo que sea demasiado útil.